# When I query to get name of column, it gives a link kind of output

Tags: php, mysql

I am querying the following query in MySQL to get the name of the column at a specific position but instead of name, I am getting a link which is not looking so useful. Can anyone help me out?

Query:

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' 
AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtablename';
```

and output is like

> column_name
>
> **tbl_structure.php?change_column=1&field=login_id&token=ac3609b5d99663ae010739dbaeee0e92**

and I want

> login_id

Comment: you have added the php tag can you show your php code.

Comment: @RahulSingh PHP is auto-suggested, I already mentioned that I am doing query in MySQL.

Comment: ``INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` ` here `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is table name or DB name ?

Comment: @BibhudattaSahoo INFORMATION_SCHEMA is an auto-generated table by phpMyAdmin that contains the information of tables and all their columns.

Comment: What is the table name where  `COLUMN_NAME` is stored and what is you condition.

Comment: Bro if I know then I will able to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are trying to fetch data from **information-schema** table which is not contains your data that contains information regarding your database
check here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html

Now in your case you can do like this

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `table-name` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='data' 
AND `TABLE_NAME`='data2';
```

**Edited:-**
You want to get the column name then check [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html)

Try this

```
$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM your-table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['Field']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: It says ): **#1146 - Table 'mysql.table_name' doesn't exist**

Comment: Change the `table-name` whit your table name

Comment: Still, have error :::;  **no column_name exists in table-name**

Comment: show me your table structure where you store the data which you want to retrieve

Comment: You are getting wrong to my query, I am asking is what is wrong in this query whether it is working perfectly for some other peoples.

Comment: Do you have any mysql knowledge ?

Comment: I am saying show me you table structure .I really want to help you.

Comment: Sorry if you get hurt but because of some security reasons, I can't tell my table structure.

Comment: Try this one once again ?